# Bootstrap Navbar behaving differently in different browsers

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my application [Bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) is not behaving as expected in Chrome but showing proper display as expected in Firefox. Please help me to fix this.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>


<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Employees</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search"
                    placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div>
        <h4 class='text-center'>Current Projects</h4>
        <table>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project Name</th>
                    <th>Project Stage</th>
                    <th>Description</th>

                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="aProject : ${projectsList}">

                    <td th:text="${aProject.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${aProject.stage}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${aProject.description}"></td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

        <h4 class='text-center'>Employee Details</h4>

        <table>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Employee Email Address</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="anEmployee : ${employeesList}">

                    <td th:text="${anEmployee.firstName} + ${anEmployee.lastName}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${anEmployee.email}"></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>

</body>
```

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

**Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

Comment: The code you have provided is working perfectly fine both in `firefox` and `chrome` and you have to edit the screenshot of google chrome because it is also showing the display of `firefox`

Comment: Is Firefox cached? Try shift-refresh. Both are modern browsers and you shouldn't see a substantial difference.

Comment: In Firefox it's working fine and I cleared cache in chrome

Comment: Check your zoom level with Ctrl-0.

Comment: Thanks all..after re-installing chrome I'm getting expected view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re installing chrome might help. Please try and let me know.